# Construct new HashMap by compressing the other map with stream()

Tags: java, java-8

I need to get new `HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>` which is `{10: [100,101], 20:[200,201]}` from `{100: [100], 101: [101], 200:[200], 201:[201]}` using stream()

I try below code but of course does not work.

```
HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put(100, new HashSet(Arrays.asList(100));
...
HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> map2 = map1.entrySet().stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(entry -> ((Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>>) entry).getKey()/10,
                     entry -> ((Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>>) entry).getValue()));
```

This raises `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without a stream:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map1.forEach((i, s) -> map2.computeIfAbsent(i / 10, ii -> new HashSet<>()).addAll(s));
```

If you still want to use a stream this will work even if your sets have more than one value:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map3 = map1.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey() / 10, HashMap::new,
                Collector.of(HashSet::new, (s, e) -> s.addAll(e.getValue()), 
                        (a, b) -> {a.addAll(b); return a;}, 
                        Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED)));
```

These both assume `map1` does not contain a null key or any null values.

Answer (score 3):

You should try `Collectors.groupingBy` :

```
map2 = map1.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .collect (Collectors.groupingBy (
                         entry -> entry.getKey()/10,
                         Collectors.mapping(entry -> entry.getValue(),Collectors.toSet()));
```

I'm not sure what's the type of the input Map. If it's `HashMap<Integer,Integer>`, my code should work as is. If it's `HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>` where the `Set<Integer>` contains just one integer (as in your example), you can change `entry.getValue()` to `entry.getValue().iterator().next()` to get that single integer.

```
map2 = map1.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .collect (Collectors.groupingBy (
                         entry -> entry.getKey()/10,
                         Collectors.mapping(entry -> entry.getValue().iterator().next(),Collectors.toSet()));
```

Come to think of it, if your input Map always contains for each key a value that is a Set with a single integer equal to that key, you can ignore the value :

```
map2 = map1.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .collect (Collectors.groupingBy (
                         entry -> entry.getKey()/10,
                         Collectors.mapping(entry -> entry.getKey(),Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: @ak79 did you see my comment at the end of the answer?

Comment: Sorry, @Eran. As you mentioned, I needed to change `entry.getValue()` into `entry.getValue().iterator().next()` .

BTW, if the `Set<Integer>` contains multiple integer, how to update your code? Actual code of mine is so.